# Azure Media Player Xamarin WebView Ugly Play Icon Background Image

Tags: android, html, azure, xamarin.forms, azure-media-services

I have tried almost everything out there to try an sort this out but have hit a wall on it.

Most of the examples out there required that you use css in the injected HTML like so:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-overlay-play-button {
  display: none;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls-overlay-play-button

video::-webkit-media-controls

video::--webkit-media-controls-play-button
```

I have seen most of the question on here, but mine is a little different as the default poster for the WebView in the xaml where I am injecting the HTML Azure media player is coming back as null when I created a new WebChromeClient and returned the Default poster back as bitmap:

[image]

My Code snippets are as follows: (xaml and the injected HTML)

```
<WebView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" WidthRequest="600" HeightRequest="300">
    <WebView.Source>
        <HtmlWebViewSource Html="{Binding LatestVideoUrl}"/>
    </WebView.Source>
</WebView>
```

The HTML string:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href=""https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/2.2.0/skins/amp-default/azuremediaplayer.min.css"" rel=""stylesheet"">
        <script src=""https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/2.2.0/azuremediaplayer.min.js""></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <video id=""azuremediaplayer"" style=""background-color: black !important; font-size: 12px !important;"" class=""azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin amp-big-play-centered"" type=""video/webm"" tabindex=""0""></video>
        <script>
            var myOptions = {
                ""nativeControlsForTouch"": false,
                ""logo"": { ""enabled"": false },
                controls: true,
                autoplay: true,
                width: ""100%"",
                height: ""100%"",
                poster: ""{Binding ThumbnailUrl}"",
                hotKeys: { ""enableFullscreen"": true }
            };
            myPlayer = amp(""azuremediaplayer"", myOptions);
            myPlayer.src([
                {
                    src: ""{Binding LatestVideoUrl}"",
                    type: ""application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml""
                }
            ]);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The video tag, I have tried to disable the controls to negate the default video player controls so that Azure Media Play can take priority but no luck.

I have also tried the Content-Security-Policy meta tag out of interest sack but it is not the correct way of doing it as its very hacky:
It did work but when I built it and deployed it to my device it made the videos very laggy and Azure Media Play controls were not showing.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
  content="default-src *;
  style-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline' ;
  media-src * ;
  img-src * 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline';
  script-src 'self' http://* https://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"/>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: were you able to overcome this?

Comment: @KodeKreachor, unfortunately not. I have seen even on the Galaxy s10 some of the apps still show that icon in any case. So it would seem to a default thing now that is becoming standard. We have learned that if you do not want that icon there you will have to build it in Java or Xcode and then build the video player there from scratch which you will have more control over.